# replace integer into exact 2 decimal after '.', for example 2 into 2.00

Tags: php

I need to represent `2.5` into exact `2.50` using php. I have used

```
 sprintf('%0.2f',2.5)
```

But it did not work. What can be the possible answer?
I have used many round off functions too like

```
round()
```

But I didn't get solution. Please help me.

Comment: I have a feeling it's just `%.2f`, but can't confirm right now.

Comment: @Pietu1998: `%d` is for integers

Comment: @axiac Whoops, fixed.

Comment: Both `%0.2f` and `%.2f` seem to work very well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format):

```
return number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');
```

Example:

```
$number= "2.5";
echo number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 2.50
```

This function returns a **string**.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. But sorry, it also displays only 2.5 not displayed 2.50

Comment: oh sorry! it was my mistake. The problem is solved. Thank you! Your help worked.... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] )
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )

$foo = "2";
echo number_format((float)$foo, 2, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 2.00
```